# Looking for a formula to determine accuracy of a sample

Tags: probability, sample, accuracy

I am looking for a formula to help me determine the accuracy of a population.

Here is my business problem.

I have about 1 million scanned documents of many types that are currently unclassified sitting in one folder.

I have used an AI program to group each different type of document into each own folder.

So I now have about 90 folders, each folder is supposed to only have one type of document in it.

So if I go into Folder A, all the documents in that folder should be the same.
If I go into Folder B, all the documents in that folder should be the same.
etc.

Now I want to check how well this model is working. I am looking for 90% accuracy.

Meaning in Folder A I am confident that 90% of the documents in that folder are all of the same type.

I could have a user go into Folder A and check every document but there could be 10k documents in there. So that manual work is not feasible.

So I want them to check a sample of the documents in folder A so that I am fairly certain that I have achieved the 90% accuracy rate.

Is there a formula that:
given a size of population (how many documents are in the folder),
desired accuracy (90%)

returns how many documents need to be validated.

And if the sample check are all correct the probability is the rest of the population is correct?

Appreciate the help,

Alex

Comment: Do you have an expected accuracy rate? If you're regularly getting 100% accuracy, you'd only need about 50 examples to very convincingly show that you're better than 90% accuracy. But if your observed accuracy is 90.1%, you'll need about a million examples to convincingly show that you're truly doing better than 90%.

Comment: I want a 90% accuracy rate. Meaning each folder is 90% accurate. If there are 10 documents in the folder 9 are the same. My goal is without checking all 10 documents can I check a subset and be confident if the subset is all the same then at least 90% of the total population is the same.

Comment: Right, what I'm getting at is the number of documents you need to review depends on what the observed accuracy values look like. If you review 10 documents and find that 0 of them are correct, you don't need to review anything else in that folder - even from a very small sample with 0% accuracy, it's incredibly unlikely that the true accuracy rate is higher than 90%. But if you find that 9 of the 10 documents are correct, it's still entirely plausible that the true accuracy is only 85%, and that's still true even if you find 90 of 100 correct.

Comment: Correct. So what I am looking for is a formula given a size of a set population how many documents do I need  to check to be at least 90% confident. So if I have 1000 documents in a folder how many do I check to be confident 90% of the population is correct. 100? 200? 300? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Were the 90 types defined in advance, and each folder labelled with the expected type? If so, they you are right to say that you can measure accuracy. For each document, there is a yes-no question "is this document in the right folder?" This is a Bernoulli trial. Your question about sample size is answered by [well known statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_sampling).

Or did you run a clustering algorithm, so the clusters are emergent from the data? Then the question about a document is "does it resemble the other documents in the same folder?". That is a harder question. There are several alternative relevant [quality scores](https://towardsdatascience.com/7-evaluation-metrics-for-clustering-algorithms-bdc537ff54d2). Sorry, I don't know what the rules are for sample size in these cases.

Comment: Hi, the way the model works is I fed one example of each document to the AI application and it used these 90 different examples to break out the remaining documents. So the 90 types are known in advance because I gave 90 examples. Now I want to check how successful the application was. Without going into each folder and checking every single document.

Comment: Great, in that case you are sampling from Bernoulli distributions, so the link will tell you the answer: in brief, the error bar is proportional to the square of the sample size, which isn't particularly good news.